# An identity among values of the logarithmic derivative of $\zeta(s)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

From some known special values of the Riemann zeta function and its derivative, one can show that
$$\gamma  =1+ \frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)} -\frac{\zeta'(0)}{\zeta(0)}+ \frac{\zeta'(-1)}{\zeta(-1)}.$$
Is there a direct proof of this identity, and, if so, does it generalize?

Note also that $$\gamma = \lim_{s\to 1}\left(\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}+ \frac{1}{s-1} \right)$$

EDIT: I just found the answers here and here:

[A kind of reflection formula for the logarithmic derivative of the zeta function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409573/a-kind-of-reflection-formula-for-the-logarithmic-derivative-of-the-zeta-function)

[About the logarithmic derivative of the Riemann zeta function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232664/about-the-logarithmic-derivative-of-the-riemann-zeta-function)